# Display:block does not stack nav element

Tags: css, nav

I'm having a little trouble getting the nav element to truly behave like a block element. I tried making a menu out of nav and a tags instead of the usual ul and li tags. That did not go as planned. My menus show up after each other as if the display:block css have no effect. I'd like to get the menus to stack, not show up after each other.

The HTML:

```
<nav id="mainmenu">
    <a href="#">Item1</a>
    <a href="#">Item2</a>
    <a href="#">Item3</a>
<nav>
<nav id="submenu">
    <a href="#">Item1</a>
    <a href="#">Item2</a>
    <a href="#">Item3</a>
<nav>
```

The CSS:

```
nav{
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT:

This is how I'd like it to be setup but I'd prefer to float the a element so I don't get the spacing issue with inline-block.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpv5H/2/

I still don't understand why floating the a tag makes all a tags show up inline when the nav element is block?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpv5H/4/

If I unfloat the a tag they align correct but I lose the padding on top and bottom of the a tag. If I add display:block to correct that all a tags stack on top of eachother. If try to correct that with a float:left the show up inline.

Inline-block on the a tag seems to fix it but then I get the spacing issue instead.

Is there a way to stack the nav elements and float the a elements and still preserve the padding to the a element?

Comment: @Molotch: See my answer below

Comment: @Molotch: updated my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:** **(after adding more details by OP)**

**BY USING `INLINE-BLOCK` TECHNIQUE:**

By using `inline-block` if you set `font-size:0px;` in `nav` (the main container having `inline-block` elements) then you will not get the extra spacing causing by `inline-block`

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/zmXNn/)

Without adding `font-size:0px;` in `nav` it will look like this:

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/zmXNn/1/)

**BY USING `FLOAT` TECHNIQUE:**

you need to add `overflow:hidden` and a `width` to prevent your `nav` element to be float.

See the changes in your CSS below:

```
nav {
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden; /* Added */
    width: 100%; /* Added */
}

nav a {
    float: left;
    padding: 2em;
}​
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/wHKtL/)

Comment: This is how I'd like it to be setup but I'd prefer to float the a element so I don't get the spacing issue with inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpv5H/2/


I still don't understand why floating the a tag makes all a tags show up inline when the nav element is block?
http://jsfiddle.net/Kpv5H/4/

If I unfloat the a tag they align correct but I lose the padding on top and bottom of the a tag. If I then add display:block to the a tag all a tags stack on top of eachother. If I the add float the show up inline. =)

Inline-block on the a tag seems to fix it but then I get the spacing issue instead.

Comment: Thanks,I noticed I didn't close my nav tags. If I do the width property isn't necessary, still need to use overflow: hidden though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to accomplish this

```
nav a{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this answer is correct? It seems like the OP wants to stack the `nav` elements, but inline the `a` elements, but your answer stacks the `a` elements. There is also the fact that this is a really old question, with an accepted answer, that nowdays could be better solved in better ways, i.e. using Flexbox.